# jQuery code to get text of children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to get the text of child elements.

I must be doing something wrong, been working on this for 2 days now.

If someone has a moment to take a look, I would be very grateful!

**CODE:**

```
function generateRemoveSectionDropDown() {
    var dropDown = document.getElementById('RemoveSectionId');
    var agendaDiv = $("[name='agenda-nestable']");
    var agendaSections = $(agendaDiv).find("ol#agenda-root>li");
    for (var i = 0; i < agendaSections.length; i++) {
        var optValue = null;
        var optText = null;
        var section = agendaSections[i];
        var sectionChildren = $(agendaSections[i]).children();
        for (var j = 0; j < sectionChildren.length; j++) {
            alert('The text from child is: ' + sectionChildren[j].text);
            optValue = j;
            optText = sectionChildren[j].text;
        }

        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = optValue;
        opt.innerText = optText;
        dropDown.appendChild(opt);
    }
}
```

**PLUNK:** http://plnkr.co/edit/jLi9epblNAtMbzezcRSY?p=preview (if you click the "Run Method", my code will run)

**Note:** Updated code.I had been hacking around with it, putting it back in a good state.

Comment: If you are already using jQuery, why `document.getElementById(`? Keep approach consistent.

Comment: @Rajesh I tried both pure JavaScript and jQuery, could not get either to work.

Comment: Where do you define `sectionListItem`?

Comment: @PhilipTennI just realized, `li` does not have `text` property. It must be `.textContent` or `$(element).text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use either-one purely (javascript/jQuery)

Working example:-

```js
function generateRemoveSectionDropDown() {
  $("[name='agenda-nestable'] ol#agenda-root>li").each(function(){ // iterate over li
    $('#RemoveSectionId').append('<option value=' + $(this).attr('id') + '>' + $(this).children('div').text() + '</option>');//create options and append to select-box
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div class="dd" name="agenda-nestable" id="nestable">
    <ol id="agenda-root" class="dd-list">
      <li class="dd-item" id="2879">
        <div class="dd-handle">Section123</div>
      </li>
      <li class="dd-item" id="2880">
        <div class="dd-handle">Section 4</div>
      </li>
      <li class="dd-item" id="2881">
        <div class="dd-handle">Section 5</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <button value onclick='generateRemoveSectionDropDown()'>Run method</button><br/><br/>
  <select id="RemoveSectionId"></select><!-- need to add it -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works like a champ.  I will accept answer as soon as StackOverflow permits.

Answer (score 1):

use foreach(**each**) function,

try this below code

```
 function generateRemoveSectionDropDown() {
        var dropDown = document.getElementById('RemoveSectionId');
        var agendaDiv = $("[name='agenda-nestable']");
        var agendaSections = $(agendaDiv).find("ol#agenda-root>li>div");
         //console.log(agendaSections);

        agendaSections.each(function(  ) {
          console.log( $(this).html() );

              // add your set of code

        }); 
 }
```